# Python A* implementation

Tags: python, a-star

I am currently working on my Python game, in ika, which uses python 2.5

I decided to use A* pathfinding for the AI. However, I find it too slow for my needs (3-4 enemies can lag the game, but I would like to supply up to 4-5 without problems). I know, that such complex search like A* is not mean to be scripted in python, but I am pretty sure, that my pathfinder is also implemented in the wrong way.

My question is: How can I speed up this algorithm? 
I wrote my own binary heap, and there are some try: except: lines inside some functions. Those lines can create large overhead? Are there better methods maintaining the open list?

I supplied the algorithm with graphics interface, for testing purposes (when the pathfinder finishes searching, it will write the number of iterations and seconds it takes to find the path, inside the ika.txt file. Also, Pressing A will do a complete search, and S does that step by step.)
Graphical version:
http://data.hu/get/6084681/A_star.rar

Also, here is a pastebin version:
http://pastebin.com/9N8ybX5F

Here is the main code I use for pathfinding:

```
import ika
import time

class Node:

  def __init__(self,x,y,parent=None,g=0,h=0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.parent = parent
    self.g = g
    self.h = h

  def cost(self):
    return self.g + self.h

  def equal(self,node):
    if self.x == node.x and self.y == node.y:
      return True
    else:
      return False

class Emerald_Pathfinder:

  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def setup(self,start,goal):
    self.start = start
    self.goal = goal
    self.openlist = [None,start]    # Implemented as binary heap
    self.closedlist = {}            # Implemented as hash
    self.onopenlist = {}            # Hash, for searching the openlist
    self.found = False
    self.current = None
    self.iterations = 0

  def lowest_cost(self):
    pass

  def add_nodes(self,current):
    nodes = []
    x = current.x
    y = current.y
    self.add_node(x+1,y,current,10,nodes)
    self.add_node(x-1,y,current,10,nodes)
    self.add_node(x,y+1,current,10,nodes)
    self.add_node(x,y-1,current,10,nodes)
    # Dont cut across corners
    up = map.is_obstacle((x,y-1),x,y-1)
    down = map.is_obstacle((x,y+1),x,y+1)
    left = map.is_obstacle((x-1,y),x-1,y)
    right = map.is_obstacle((x+1,y),x+1,y)
    if right == False and down == False:
      self.add_node(x+1,y+1,current,14,nodes)
    if left == False and up == False:
      self.add_node(x-1,y-1,current,14,nodes)
    if right == False and up == False:
      self.add_node(x+1,y-1,current,14,nodes)
    if left == False and down == False:
      self.add_node(x-1,y+1,current,14,nodes)
    return nodes

  def heuristic(self,x1,y1,x2,y2):
    return (abs(x1-x2)+abs(y1-y2))*10

  def add_node(self,x,y,parent,cost,list):
    # If not obstructed
    if map.is_obstacle((x,y),x,y) == False:
      g = parent.g + cost
      h = self.heuristic(x,y,self.goal.x,self.goal.y)
      node = Node(x,y,parent,g,h)
      list.append(node)

  def ignore(self,node,current):
    # If its on the closed list, or open list, ignore
    try:
      if self.closedlist[(node.x,node.y)] == True:
        return True
    except:
      pass
    # If the node is on the openlist, do the following
    try:
      # If its on the open list
      if self.onopenlist[(node.x,node.y)] != None:
        # Get the id number of the item on the real open list
        index = self.openlist.index(self.onopenlist[(node.x,node.y)])
        # If one of the coordinates equal, its not diagonal.
        if node.x == current.x or node.y == current.y:
          cost = 10
        else:
          cost = 14
        # Check, is this items G cost is higher, than the current G + cost
        if self.openlist[index].g > (current.g + cost):
          # If so, then, make the list items parent, the current node.
          self.openlist[index].g = current.g + cost
          self.openlist[index].parent = current
          # Now resort the binary heap, in the right order.
          self.resort_binary_heap(index)
        # And ignore the node
        return True
    except:
      pass
    return False

  def resort_binary_heap(self,index):
    m = index
    while m > 1:
      if self.openlist[m/2].cost() > self.openlist[m].cost():
        temp = self.openlist[m/2]
        self.openlist[m/2] = self.openlist[m]
        self.openlist[m] = temp
        m = m / 2
      else:
        break

  def heap_add(self,node):
    self.openlist.append(node)
    # Add item to the onopenlist.
    self.onopenlist[(node.x,node.y)] = node
    m = len(self.openlist)-1
    while m > 1:
      if self.openlist[m/2].cost() > self.openlist[m].cost():
        temp = self.openlist[m/2]
        self.openlist[m/2] = self.openlist[m]
        self.openlist[m] = temp
        m = m / 2
      else:
        break

  def heap_remove(self):
    if len(self.openlist) == 1:
      return
    first = self.openlist[1]
    # Remove the first item from the onopenlist
    self.onopenlist[(self.openlist[1].x,self.openlist[1].y)] = None
    last = self.openlist.pop(len(self.openlist)-1)
    if len(self.openlist) == 1:
      return last
    else:
      self.openlist[1] = last
    v = 1
    while True:
      u = v
      # If there is two children
      if (2*u)+1 < len(self.openlist):
        if self.openlist[2*u].cost() <= self.openlist[u].cost():
          v = 2*u
        if self.openlist[(2*u)+1].cost() <= self.openlist[v].cost():
          v = (2*u)+1
      # If there is only one children
      elif 2*u < len(self.openlist):
        if self.openlist[2*u].cost() <= self.openlist[u].cost():
          v = 2*u
      # If at least one child is smaller, than parent, swap them
      if u != v:
        temp = self.openlist[u]
        self.openlist[u] = self.openlist[v]
        self.openlist[v] = temp
      else:
        break
    return first

  def iterate(self):
    # If the open list is empty, exit the game
    if len(self.openlist) == 1:
      ika.Exit("no path found")
    # Expand iteration by one
    self.iterations += 1
    # Make the current node the lowest cost
    self.current = self.heap_remove()
    # Add it to the closed list
    self.closedlist[(self.current.x,self.current.y)] = True
    # Are we there yet?
    if self.current.equal(self.goal) == True:
      # Target reached
      self.goal = self.current
      self.found = True
      print self.iterations
    else:
      # Add the adjacent nodes, and check them
      nodes_around = self.add_nodes(self.current)
      for na in nodes_around:
        if self.ignore(na,self.current) == False:
          self.heap_add(na)

  def iterateloop(self):
    time1 = time.clock()
    while 1:
      # If the open list is empty, exit the game
      if len(self.openlist) == 1:
        ika.Exit("no path found")
      # Expand iteration by one
      self.iterations += 1
      # Make the current node the lowest cost
      self.current = self.heap_remove()
      # Add it to the closed list
      self.closedlist[(self.current.x,self.current.y)] = True
      # Are we there yet?
      if self.current.equal(self.goal) == True:
        # Target reached
        self.goal = self.current
        self.found = True
        print "Number of iterations"
        print self.iterations
        break
      else:
        # Add the adjacent nodes, and check them
        nodes_around = self.add_nodes(self.current)
        for na in nodes_around:
          if self.ignore(na,self.current) == False:
            self.heap_add(na)
    time2 = time.clock()
    time3 = time2-time1
    print "Seconds to find path:"
    print time3

class Map:

  def __init__(self):
    self.map_size_x = 20
    self.map_size_y = 15
    self.obstructed = {} # Library, containing x,y couples
    self.start = [2*40,3*40]
    self.unit = [16*40,8*40]

  def is_obstacle(self,couple,x,y):
    if (x >= self.map_size_x or x < 0) or (y >= self.map_size_y or y < 0):
      return True
    try:
      if self.obstructed[(couple)] != None:
        return True
    except:
      return False

def render_screen():
  # Draw the Character
  ika.Video.DrawRect(map.start[0],map.start[1],map.start[0]+40,map.start[1]+40,ika.RGB(40,200,10),1)
  # Draw walls
  for x in range(0,map.map_size_x):
    for y in range(0,map.map_size_y):
      if map.is_obstacle((x,y),x,y) == True:
        ika.Video.DrawRect(x*40,y*40,(x*40)+40,(y*40)+40,ika.RGB(168,44,0),1)
  # Draw openlist items
  for node in path.openlist:
    if node == None:
      continue
    x = node.x
    y = node.y
    ika.Video.DrawRect(x*40,y*40,(x*40)+40,(y*40)+40,ika.RGB(100,100,100,50),1)
  # Draw closedlist items
  for x in range(0,map.map_size_x):
    for y in range(0,map.map_size_y):
      try:
        if path.closedlist[(x,y)] == True:
          ika.Video.DrawRect(x*40,y*40,(x*40)+20,(y*40)+20,ika.RGB(0,0,255))
      except:
        pass
  # Draw the current square
  try:
    ika.Video.DrawRect(path.current.x*40,path.current.y*40,(path.current.x*40)+40,(path.current.y*40)+40,ika.RGB(128,128,128), 1)
  except:
    pass
  ika.Video.DrawRect(mouse_x.Position(),mouse_y.Position(),mouse_x.Position()+8,mouse_y.Position()+8,ika.RGB(128,128,128), 1)
  # Draw the path, if reached
  if path.found == True:
    node = path.goal
    while node.parent:
      ika.Video.DrawRect(node.x*40,node.y*40,(node.x*40)+40,(node.y*40)+40,ika.RGB(40,200,200),1)
      node = node.parent
  # Draw the Target
  ika.Video.DrawRect(map.unit[0],map.unit[1],map.unit[0]+40,map.unit[1]+40,ika.RGB(128,40,200),1)

def mainloop():
  while 1:
    render_screen()
    if mouse_middle.Pressed():
      # Iterate pathfinder
      if path.found == False:
        path.iterateloop()
    elif mouse_right.Pressed():
      # Iterate pathfinder by one
      if path.found == False:
        path.iterate()
    elif ika.Input.keyboard["A"].Pressed():
      # Iterate pathfinder
      if path.found == False:
        path.iterateloop()
    elif ika.Input.keyboard["S"].Pressed():
      # Iterate pathfinder by one
      if path.found == False:
        path.iterate()
    elif mouse_left.Position():
      # Add a square to the map, to be obstructed
      if path.iterations == 0:
        x = mouse_x.Position()
        y = mouse_y.Position()
        map.obstructed[(int(x/40),int(y/40))] = True
    # Mouse preview
    x = mouse_x.Position()
    y = mouse_y.Position()
    mx = int(x/40)*40
    my = int(y/40)*40
    ika.Video.DrawRect(mx,my,mx+40,my+40,ika.RGB(150,150,150,70),1)
    ika.Video.ShowPage()
    ika.Input.Update()

map = Map()
path = Emerald_Pathfinder()
path.setup(Node(map.start[0]/40,map.start[1]/40),Node(map.unit[0]/40,map.unit[1]/40))
mouse_middle = ika.Input.mouse.middle
mouse_right = ika.Input.mouse.right
mouse_left = ika.Input.mouse.left
mouse_x = ika.Input.mouse.x
mouse_y = ika.Input.mouse.y
# Initialize loop
mainloop()
```

I appreciate any help!
(sorry for any spelling mistakes, English is not my native language)

Comment: It might be worth looking for an existing library to do this (which would probably be an extension module written in C), as that way you don't need to re-implement it and it'll be faster. Obviously, if you are developing for the sake of learning, then don't worry about that.

Comment: Also, this question appears to be about improving working code, so you might want to post it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead. In general, please post the code in the question, rather than linking to it externally.

Comment: "an extension module written in C"

Are there any tutorials on this, or any "database" for already written extensions? I can't find any good source on this, and if this is worth for this kind of thing (pathfinding for games)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a proper implementation in python will be fast enough for your purposes. But the boost library has an astar implementation and python bindings. https://github.com/erwinvaneijk/bgl-python